# Copy Table from a Server and Insert into another Server: What is wrong with this T-SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, copy, sql-server-2014, linked-server

I am using `SQL Server 2014`. I have created the following `T-SQL` query which I uploaded to my local SQL server to run as a job process on a daily basis at a specific time. However, I noticed that it failed to run. If I run it manually in `SSMS`, it runs correctly.
What is preventing the query to run as an automated process? Is it a syntax issue?

```
USE MyDatabase
GO

DELETE FROM ExchangeRate -- STEP 1

;WITH MAINQUERY_CTE AS ( --STEP 2
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM [178.25.0.20].HMS_ARL.dbo.ExchangeRate
    ) q

)
INSERT INTO ExchangeRate --STEP 3
SELECT *
FROM MAINQUERY_CTE
```

Basically, the function of the query is to copy a table named `ExchangeRate` from the live server and paste its content in a table of the same name (which already exists on my local server).

**Error Log shows the following message:**

> Description: Executing the query "USE MyDatabase   DELETE FROM
>   ExchangeRate..." failed with the following error: "Access to the
>   remote server is denied because no login-mapping exists.". Possible
>   failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set
>   correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established
>   correctly.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned
>   DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  10:59:30 AM  Finished: 10:59:30 AM 
>   Elapsed:  0.422 seconds.  The package execution failed.  NOTE: The
>   step was retried the requested number of times (3) without succeeding.
>   The step failed.

Comment: I have edited my post with the error log message. Thanks.

Comment: `"Access to the remote server is denied because no login-mapping exists.".` That says it all. The credentials under which the job runs, does not have access to the remote server

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to add login details/mapping inside a Query? Or should that be done at a different level. I guess the query runs fine on my local PC because the mapping has been done on that PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you have to create Linked Server in your local server to the Remote server?